# SQL Developer Data is not compatible with column definition

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to insert data into my table but I am receiving this error:

"SQL Developer Data is not compatible with column definition or is not available for a nut nullable column"

The column that is getting this error has data of the form 7391DBDF-40D5-E523-80C2-3863BB43AC67.

I believe this is a uniqueidentifer but but I'm not sure how one would insert this datatype into SQL Developer.

nvm: got it. Use Varchar

Comment: is that REALLY the error message you received? I've not ever seen that one, where it starts SQL Developer Data...

Comment: also, don't use VARCHAR, use VARCHAR2

Comment: @thatjeffsmith getting the same error, what's odd is that they only occur for columns that are of type NUMBER in the table.

Comment: @JacKTrocinskI start a new question, and share your table ddl and insert code and i'll take a look - otherwise you're asking me to guess

Answer (score 0):

Same error importing good data into a `number` column with SQLDeveloper, problem was not specifying precision and scale on the column.

Solved by setting `size` to `28,0`.

[image]